# My SQL installed in `Program Files` and can't see the `my.ini` files

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlyog

In my machine (Windows 10) two MySQl versions are needed. The Project "A" is running in XAMPP. When I've started my second project, I've stopped the first SQL services and installed MySQL 5.7. In that I need to set  `lower_case_table_names = 2` for the case sensitive method.

I google it, they say:

1. open your MySQL configuration file: `[drive]\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini`
2. look up for: `# The MySQL server [mysqld]`
3. add this right below it: `lower_case_table_names = 2`
4. save the file and restart MySQL service

I know that it's for XAMPP only.

But I've installed MySQL in `Program Files`. Here I couldn't able to see `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\my.ini` files. Then where should I set the `lower_case_table_names = 2` value?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In XAMPP use the "Control Panel" to find the `mysql.ini` config file.

In a regular Windows install of MySQL the `.ini` file sits in `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server`.